# Get maximum frequency item with its corresponding number

Tags: python, text, counter

I have list of ID for example list1=[ID1, ID1, ID3, ID1, ID5, ID1], and each ID has its corresponding probability for example list2=[0.9, 0.92, 0.8, 0.91, 0.7, 0.9]. I want to achieve maximum frequency item inside list1 with its summed corresponding probabilities from list2. for example
ID1:4(frequency), 3.63(summed probability)
ID3:1(frequency), 0.8(probability)
ID5:1(frequency), 0.7(probability)

I can get the frequency from the following code:

```
from collections import Counter
counter_list = Counter(list1)
print("Voting of each predicted class", counter_list)
```

The above code resulted in:
    [{ID1:4}, {ID3:1}, {ID5:1}]
It return me the frequency only, but I don't know how to connect the first list with the second one or to damage them in one list of 2D and taking the first item for counting frequency and second item for increasing probability counter. I'm new in python, can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1=['ID1', 'ID1', 'ID3', 'ID1', 'ID5', 'ID1']
list2=[0.9, 0.92, 0.8, 0.91, 0.7, 0.9]

d = {}
dict = {}
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y) # {'ID1': [0.9, 0.92, 0.91, 0.9], 'ID3': [0.8], 'ID5': [0.7]}
    dict[x] = (len(d[x]),sum(d[x])) # calculating frequency and probability for each key
print (dict)
```

output:

```
{'ID1': (4, 3.63), 'ID3': (1, 0.8), 'ID5': (1, 0.7)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the items from both lists, and the position of each item is the same on both lists, you can use a `for` with the `zip` function to iterate over both lists at the same time. Example:

```
for id_name, prob in zip(list1, list2):
    print(list1, list2)
```

To save the results counting the repetitions and summing a dictionary, where the key is the id, and the value is a list containing two values: the first is the count of the id, and the second the sum of the probabilities:

```
my_dict = {}
for id_name, prob in zip(list1, list2):
    if id_name not in my_dict:
        my_dict[id_name] = [0, 0]

    my_dict[id_name][0] = my_dict[id_name][0] + 1
    my_dict[id_name][1] = my_dict[id_name][1] + prob
```

The ending result is a dict containing the counts and the summed probabilities.